# .htaccess being ignored - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to use the `.htaccess` file on my Apache server.

Here is what my `.htaccess` looks like

```
# 1 YEAR
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|svg|woff|eot|ttf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public"
</FilesMatch>

# 1 WEEK
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|png|gif|css|js)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>

# Add correct content-type for fonts 
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/otf .otf
AddType font/x-woff .woff
AddType image/svg+xml .svg

# Compress compressible fonts
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf font/otf image/svg+xml
```

I enabled mod_rewrite using `a2enmod rewrite`

The tutorials I followed told me to edit the file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` but there isn't a file by the name `default` in that folder. There was a `000-default.conf` instead in the same path. But that file didn't have the part

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

which I'm supposed to edit.

This is the contents of `000-default.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

However `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` had the exact same part. So I replaced `AllowOverride None` over there to `AllowOverride All`. I restarted the server after that.

However the `.htaccess` file is still not being loaded. If I add gibberish to the `.htaccess` file everything still works fine meaning it didn't get loaded.

What did I miss here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The isssue was that I was placing the `.htaccess` file in `/var/www/` while my `DocumentRoot` for my website was pointing to a different directory. Moving the `.htaccess` file to that folder solved the issue.

Answer (score 8):

First of all, the name of the file doesn't really matters. 000-default.conf, while not really common seems good to me.

**Modify your site configuration**

There are 2 major things you have to consider when serving .htaccess files :

```
AccessFileName .htaccess
AllowOverride All
```

As said in the [apache2 doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#allowoverride), you must declare `AllowOverride` in a **Directory** section. That's why it didn't work when setting  it in main config file.

I'd advise you to just paste those 4 lines in **/etc/apache2/000-default.conf** inside the **Virtualhost** section and it should work:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

(assuming your root directory is /var/www)

You don't have to set **AccessFileName** as default is *.htaccess*.

If it doesn't work and you have more than 1 file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`

Apache might use another config thant 000-default.conf. Just check which of those are symlinked to */etc/apache2/sites-enabled*. If there's still more than 1, you might want to disable every other enabled site just to be sure.

If it still doesn't work, just check file ownership & permissions.

Comment: Upvoted, great answer!  BTW, I looked FOREVER for "AccesFileName", that's a typo, I fixed that up for ya'. =)